# Simple Combination Problem with More Spaces to Fill than Items to Place

Tags: statistics

The problem is to seat 9 people into 3 cars of which car A has 2 seats, car B has 4 seats, and car C has 5 seats. All cars must be driven.

I have reasoned that at least one person must be in every car to be the driver. This reduces the total people by 3 to 6 people that may be placed into the remaining seats which are 8. Hence my problem.

How do I address the extra seats?

I believe I may be able to in invoke the equation:

6! / (1!)(3!)(4!) = 5

the denominator represents the available seats per car.

This result gives me two values which I was going to add together.

What is disconcerting is I obtain such low values: such as the 5 above and the driver computation = 9!/(6!)(3!) = 84 which I believe is correct.

If I propose phantom riders to fill the empty seats to subsequently remove with a division such as:

8! / (1!)(3!)(4!)(2!) = 140

this also seems low relative to the other problems I have been solving.

Any insight to how I am looking at this problem incorrectly?

Comment: Do you distinguish the driver in each car?  That is, do you count car A with Alice driving and Bob riding as different from car A with Bob driving and Alice riding? If so, start by seating the drivers-how many ways to do that?

Comment: Yes, I am subtracting 3 from the total of 9 to form the combination 9 choose 3. 9!/(9-3)!3! = 3024 way to place 3 people from 9 into 3 places. However, my misunderstanding is how to place the remaining 6 people into 8 seats.

Comment: Note that [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%21%2F6%213%21) considers $9!/6!3!=(9!/6!)*3!=3024$, not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be dividing by $3!$ because the driver seats are distinguished, though your calculation of $3024$ actually multiplies by it.  You have $9$ ways to choose the driver of car A, $8$ ways to choose the driver of car B, and $7$ ways to choose the driver of car C for $504$ ways to choose the drivers.  Now I don't see an easy way except casework.  There may be a cute stars-and-bars argument.  You can distribute the people $(1,3,2),(1,2,3),(1,1,4),(0,3,3),(0,2,4)$.  You can do the first in ${6 \choose 1}{5 \choose 3}$ ways and so on.

Comment: You're right. I did the calculator computation too quickly. The problem seems to be fairly complicated if it requires casework. I thought of this path as well and became intimidated. I am impressed though that this is a problem among others from a text that are not as demanding which suggests there may be an answer that does not involve cases. However, I do not know which is why I am seeking clarification.